# Error when migrating from Jboss-7.4.0 to Jboss-7.4.5

Tags: openssl, jboss, wildfly, jboss7.x, elytron

When I am migrating to jboss-7.4.5 from jboss-7.4.0, I am getting this below error when starting my server.

> 12:53:55,533 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.9.1.Final-redhat-00001
> 12:53:58,921 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001
> 12:53:58,930 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001
> 12:53:59,040 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: JBoss EAP 7.4.5.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.13.Final-redhat-00001) starting
> 12:54:00,206 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.15.12.Final-redhat-00001
> 12:54:04,115 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 7) WFLYCTL0033: Extension 'security' is deprecated and may not be supported in future versions
> 12:54:05,451 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=native-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,452 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,463 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 12) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'username' in the resource at address '/subsystem=remoting/remote-outbound-connection=remote-ejb-connection' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,464 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=remoting/remote-outbound-connection=remote-ejb-connection' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 23) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'protocol' in the resource at address '/subsystem=remoting/remote-outbound-connection=remote-ejb-connection' is deprecated, and may be removed in a future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
> 12:54:05,476 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYDS0015: Re-attempting failed deployment sopra-banking-xchannel-4.x-ib-connect.war
> 12:54:05,910 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=elytron/aggregate-providers=combined-providers' are not available:
> org.wildfly.security.providers.openssl; Possible registration points for this capability:
> /subsystem=elytron/aggregate-providers=*
> /subsystem=elytron/provider-loader=*
> org.wildfly.security.providers.elytron; Possible registration points for this capability:
> /subsystem=elytron/aggregate-providers=*
> /subsystem=elytron/provider-loader=*
> 12:54:05,913 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
> 12:54:05,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0050: JBoss EAP 7.4.5.GA (WildFly Core 15.0.13.Final-redhat-00001) stopped in 7ms

I have applied the patch to jboss-7.4.0 downloaded from red hat website

I have tried by replacing the jboss-7.4.0 version standalone.xml but it did not work

Comment: This looks like an error in your configuration. I would contact support as they might have a quick fix or know the fix for this. Essentially though the `combined-providers` likely has a bad value or a missing value really.

Comment: The same configuration worked on other system. Is there any extra certificate or config required for jboss 7.4.5?